# MySQL two rows into columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One has order information with an order id, and the other table has order detail information. order_details has multiple rows for each order_id. I'd like a single query that would pull the order information, and then add a 'column' for each entry on the order_details table.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Confused as why this is all in two tables. Aren't the words "information" and "details" synonyms? Can you combine them any way? Also confused about what you mean by add a column for each entry? In HTML? what is the set up of the details table?

Comment: Is this possible? Almost certainly, yes. How? You tell us - we can't give you a query without knowing the columns in your database and exactly what you want returned. Ask a more precise question and I'm sure people will be happy to help you out.

Comment: I was doing what @gahooa suggested below. If anyone knows a better way I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in MySQL, or in any SQL that I know of, with the *exception* of a highly hardcoded query with excessive joins or subqueries.

This type of problem is typically relegated to the domain of programming languages.  If you have an ad-hoc need for a query to do this, then something like this would do it (you will have to quote the keyword `order`)

SQL example:

```
SELECT 
  order_id, 
  date, 
  (select amt from order_detail where order_id=order.order_id and detail_line=1),
  (select amt from order_detail where order_id=order.order_id and detail_line=2),
  (select amt from order_detail where order_id=order.order_id and detail_line=3),
  (select amt from order_detail where order_id=order.order_id and detail_line=4),
FROM 
  order
WHERE 
  order_id = 1234
```

Comment: That's what I was doing, but I was hoping there was something a bit "prettier". But if it's not possible, it's not possible I suppose. Thanks!